# Copy parent fields to child fields

Tags: trigger

I have a account object for that object i have a parent account in that parent account i have a number field called "Productalue". when ever productvalue is 0 or 1 at that time i have to copy the Account name of parent account to child Account field "childParent"can any one help on this by using trigger.

Comment: Have you try Workflow field update?

Answer (score 0):

Here are pointers for to acheive your goal:

1. Trigger After Insert/Update on Parent Account Object
2. On Insert check for the productvalue is 0 or 1 and if yes get it's child Accounts and Update Parent Account name to child Account.
3. On Update check if the productvalue  is changed and also check for current value is 0 or 1. If both conditions satisfy then Update it's child accounts.
4. IF productvalue is changed from 0 or 1 to other value then Update it's child Accounts as per desired value.

Hope this helps!!